After finding that $e^{it}$'s image by a TILS is an exponential of the same periodicity, how to prove $\cos$'s image is $\cos$? Sinusoidal fidelity
I am trying to prove that the image of a cosine by a Time-Invariant Linear System is a cosine.
I start with $$\cos(t) =\frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2} =x_1(t) + x_2(t)$$
Let's call the image $y_1(t) + y_2(t)$.
We'll prove $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are exponential functions and that they are $2\pi$-periodic.
Indeed, if I input $x_1(t+t_0) = x_1(t) x_1(t_0)$ in the TILS I get $y_1(t+t_0)=y_1(t)y_1(t_0)$, which shows $y_1$ is an exponential.
Now, to prove periodicity, note that $x_1(t+2\pi) = x_1(t)$ after inputting in the TILS, the ouput is $y_1(t+2\pi) = y_1(t)$, which shows $y_1$ is $2\pi$-periodic.
Of course the same applies to $x_2(t)$.
I wonder now, how to prove that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are complex conjugates.
Could I reason like this: "the two possibilities are $y_1,y_2= e^{it}$ or one of the two equal to $e^{it}$ and the other equal to $e^{-it}$. If I assume the first possibility, we have that $y_1=y_2$ and  because TILS is injective that would mean $x_1=x_2$. Which is impossible." Can I reason like this? Are TILS always injective?

It's straightforward to show that the mapping implemented by a linear time-invariant (LTI) system is not necessarily injective. Take as an example an ideal low pass filter and two input signals with spectra that are identical inside the filter's passband, but that differ in the stopband. The filter maps both input signals to the same output signal, even though the input signals are different.
We know that the input-output relation of an LTI system is described by convolution:
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\tau)x(t-\tau)d\tau\tag{1}$$
where $h(t)$ is the system's impulse response. For $x(t)=e^{j\omega_0t}$ we obtain from $(1)$
$$y(t)=e^{j\omega_0t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\tau)e^{-j\omega_0\tau}d\tau=e^{j\omega_0t}H(j\omega_0)\tag{2}$$
where $H(j\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $h(t)$, which is also called the frequency response of the system.
Consequently, for the input signal
$$x(t)=\cos(\omega_0t)=\frac12\left(e^{j\omega_0t}+e^{-j\omega_0t}\right)\tag{3}$$
we obtain from $(2)$ and using linearity
$$y(t)=\frac12\left(H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}+H(-j\omega_0)e^{-j\omega_0t}\right)\tag{4}$$
Now we only need to confirm that the two terms in parentheses are complex conjugates. This is indeed the case if we assume that the impulse response $h(t)$ is real-valued because then we have
$$H^*(j\omega)=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right)^*=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{j\omega t}dt=H(-j\omega)\tag{5}$$
With $(5)$, Eq. $(4)$ can be rewritten as
$$y(t)=\textrm{Re}\left\{H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}\right\}=\big|H(e^{j\omega_0})\big|\cos\left(\omega_0t+\phi(\omega_0)\right)\tag{6}$$
where I used $\phi(\omega)=\arg\{H(j\omega)\}$.
